# An error occurred while loading the web debug toolbar (404: not found)?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, symfony, swiftmailer

Hi I'm using Symfony (Swiftmailer) to send an emails, the problem that I have is:

> An error occurred while loading the web debug toolbar (404: not found)
>   Do you want to open the profiler?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0wzu.jpg)

The emails were sent successfully but the problem is I can't render any *.html.twig.

---

I tried != solution like command php bin/console debug:event-dispatcher and the .htacces like

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>    
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /app.php [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        # When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of
        # the start page to the front controller explicitly so that the website
        # and the generated links can still be used.
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
        # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

But all the solutions proposed on the net do not work for me, thanks for helping.

Comment: check the firewall and routing for debug toolbar. Is the problem only with Swiftmailer?

Comment: yes the problem only with swiftmailer

Comment: when i look in the config_dev.yml i found the folow code : web_profiler:
    toolbar: false
    intercept_redirects: false

Comment: Which version of symfony is being used?

Answer (score 0):

when i look in the config_dev.yml i found the folow code :

```
web_profiler:
    toolbar: true
    intercept_redirects: false
```

i turn the toolbar value to false, it work correctly like

```
web_profiler:
    toolbar: false
    intercept_redirects: false
```

are this solution touche others file and cause me other problems?